# Pandas `read_sql` SUM column differs from CLI output

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a very typical one-many relationship from table orders -> order_details with primary key `order_uuid`. I would like to aggregate this in some way for analysis in Python.

When I execute the following SQL query on my Postgres database from the CLI I received the expected results:

Query:

```
SELECT orders.order_uuid, orders.checkout_datetime,
                            SUM(order_details.price * order_details.count) as total
                        FROM orders
                        INNER JOIN order_details 
                        ON orders.order_uuid = order_details.order_uuid
                        WHERE orders.open = 0
                        GROUP BY orders.order_uuid
                        ORDER BY orders.checkout_datetime DESC;
```

Result:

```
              order_uuid              |     checkout_datetime      |       total
--------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------
 7b40e9eb-2187-463e-92db-b8c531f71b88 | 2021-07-05 17:44:32.414564 |                2.2
 4b418345-9354-4a3c-a2a4-82a735f94f16 | 2021-07-05 16:39:52.192342 |                0.6
 0da08b1d-7133-4a23-9d88-9cf0fd776ab1 | 2021-07-05 16:36:24.099433 |                9.5
 44ee0e22-e584-46b9-b272-b62c69098de1 | 2021-07-05 15:41:22.142069 |                0.8
 52438467-0b2b-4731-a8a4-ec35c752cc4f | 2021-07-05 15:05:02.411967 |                0.3
etc etc.
```

When I execute the **exact same statement** within the `pandas.io.sql` `read_sql` method, my `total` column becomes `None`!

```
python 3.7

df = pandas.io.sql.read_sql(<ABOVE QUERY>, con=my_con)

df.to_string()
```

Output:

```
                              order_uuid          checkout_datetime total
0   b703ab2d-4b09-4ff1-a48c-ccfa411f0150 2021-07-05 17:49:31.722608  None
1   bf2b66ed-d310-4be8-899e-c7788d5fce31 2021-07-05 17:44:50.593600  None
2   4417b7f0-81cb-4afe-adf7-2bf8f36e62e6 2021-07-05 16:36:23.627361  None
3   63a9eb68-5656-4551-9bc5-dd5b8c91f48e 2021-07-05 15:47:09.557005  None
4   7013a84d-f6f1-4877-9963-0db6b4117577 2021-07-04 16:18:23.556719  None
```

My connection is a `psycopg2` database connection to a remote heroku (AWS hosted) database if that helps.

Comment: Are you certain that the underlying data be the same for both queries?

Comment: Hi, Tim, it's the same table, I just happened to copy different rows

Answer (score 0):

Tim's comment tipped me off in the correct direction - the problem was not with any method. I had 'WHERE orders.open = %s' and supplied the WRONG query parameter (1 instead of 0).